# Serialization of F# mutable variable to JSON using Json.NET generates duplicated items

Tags: json, serialization, f#, json.net

Here is my code:

```
 open Newtonsoft.Json
 open Newtonsoft.Json.Converters

 type T = {
     mutable name : string;
     mutable height : int;
     }

 let a = { name = "abc"; height = 180;}
 a.height  <- 200
 let b = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(a, Formatting.Indented)
 printfn "%s"  b
```

The output of the code is:

```
{
  "name@": "abc",
  "height@": 200,
  "name": "abc",
  "height": 200
}
```

How can I avoid the outputs with '@' in the properity?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
[<CLIMutable>]
[<JsonObject(MemberSerialization=MemberSerialization.OptOut)>]
type T = {
    name : string;
    height : int;
    }
```

`MemberSerialization.OptOut` causes only public members to be serialized (skipping private fields which are an implementation detail of records). The `CLIMutable` attribute is [intended specifically for serialization](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/fsharpteam/archive/2012/07/19/more-about-fsharp-3.0-language-features.aspx) and saves from having to prefix each member with `mutable`.

Comment: The features added by [<CLIMutable>] are not exposed to F# apparently. [<JsonObject(MemberSerialization=MemberSerialization.OptOut)>] is the default behavior (so no difference on the outputs). I tried with MemberSerialization.fields option, which reduce the outputs to {
  "name@": "abc",
  "height@": 200
}. Still not ideal.

Comment: I still needs to add "mutable" keyword as [<CLIMutable>] doesn't make the variable mutable in F# code. With "mutable", the output contains '@'.

Comment: `CLIMutable` addresses the most common case of serializing records while treating them as immutable within F#. If you need mutable records you'll have to use `DataMemberAttribute` as Konrad mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

With the help of [`DataMemberAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.runtime.serialization.datamemberattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) you can specify names of the serialized members:

```
type T = {
    [<field: DataMember(Name="name")>]
    mutable name : string;
    [<field: DataMember(Name="height")>]
    mutable height : int;
}
```

Comment: Add a [<DataContract>] above your 'type T =' and it will work.

Comment: This works, but is a bit tedious, especially for records with many fields.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to add attributes [<...>] in front of the property? Because that attribute will only apply to the property, not to the generated backend. Not sure which attribute JSON.NET reacts to, however.

Comment: JSON.Net works with DataContract/DataMember and JsonObject/JsonProperty attributes.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and I had to look eventually this was what worked, after so much digging through Json.Net docs.

```
 open System
 open System.Runtime.Serialization

 [<CLIMutable>]
 [<DataContract>]
 type T = {
    [<DataMember>] mutable name : string;
    [<DataMember>] mutable height : int }
```