# Shortest syntax for Entity Framework compatible POCO

Tags: entity-framework, f#, poco

I need F# to work with Entity Framework seemlesly. I am trying to adapt example from here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2011/04/04/f-code-first-development-with-entity-framework-4-1/
The problem is that record declaration is so scary there that it is just unacceptable for me.

```
type public Car() =
    let mutable m_ID : int = 0
    let mutable m_name : string = ""

    [<Key>]
    member public this.ID        with    get()   = m_ID
                                 and     set v   = m_ID <- v
    member public this.Name      with    get()   = m_name
                                 and     set v   = m_name <- v
```

I have tried CLIMutable in such a way:

```
module Program    

[<CLIMutable>]
type Car = {        
    Name:string        
}        
let c = new Car(Name = "Honda")
```

It results in error: "No contructors are available for the type 'Car'".
As I understand this answer might be an explanation:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/28845368/585819

I also tried things like:

```
[<CLIMutable>]
type Car = 
    { 
    ID:int        
    } member this.Name = ""
```

The error is the same. I feel really disappointed. Can somebody help with this?

Comment: What I usually do is create my POCO classes and DbContext in a separate project. That way I can also leverage code first migrations.

Comment: @OJRaqueño I have tried putting them in separate project (library). But the error is the same. I don't know, may be there are some special compiling options required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what seems to be working for me. This is not a record but class. Also it probably could not be named POCO.

```
//file DataModel.fs
module DataModel
open System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations
open System.Data.Entity
type Car()=
    [<Key>]
    member val Id = 0 with get,set
    member val Name = "" with get,set

type public CLCars() =
    inherit  DbContext()
    member val Cars: DbSet<Car> = base.Set<Car>() with get,set

//file Program.fs
module Program
open DataModel   

   let db = new CLCars()
   let c = new Car(Name="Honda")
   db.Cars.Add(c) |> ignore
   db.SaveChanges() |> ignore
```

Answer (score 5):

The `CLIMutable` attribute does not have any impact on F# use-sites. The added default constructor is inaccessible from F# user-code and so are mutable properties. If you want to use EFs change tracking (from within F#), records are not a good choice (because you can't change it unless you declare all fields `mutable`).
If possible consider using e.g. the [SQL Provider](http://fsprojects.github.io/SQLProvider/). On the other hand e.g. [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net) supports serializing/deserializing POCOs and thusly F# records.

As the record looks immutable from F# perspective, regular construction applies:

```
let c = { Name = "Honda" }
```

or (to disambiguate, if you also have e.g. `type Person = { Name : string }`)

```
let c = { Car.Name = "Honda" }
let c : Car = { Name = "Honda" }
let c = { Name = "Honda" } : Car
```

Comment: I don't need EF change tracking. The only reason I want to use EF is that it creates DB schema from POCOs. I have not found any alternative tool for this.