# F#: JsonConvert.SerializeObject() saves the same data multiple times

Tags: json, f#, json.net

I am new to programming and F# is my first language.

I followed the advice given to me [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29694694/f-inability-to-read-json-files) to use NewtonSoft.Json. Here are some relevant parts of my code:

```
    [<CLIMutable>]
    [<JsonObject(MemberSerialization=MemberSerialization.OptOut)>]
    type FighterSummary =
        { 
            mutable fighter: string; 
            mutable record: string option; 
            mutable reach: float option; 
            mutable stance: string option; 
        }

    let fighterFilesDir = @"G:\Fighter Pages"
    let fighterFiles = Directory.GetFiles(fighterFilesDir)
    let fighterGroups = splitArrayIntoGroups fighterFiles 50

    for group in fighterGroups do
        let fighterStats =   seq { 
                                    for file in group do
                                        let html = File.ReadAllText(file)
                                        let fighterOverview = getFighterSummary html
                                        printfn "Extracted %s's overview." (Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file))
                                        yield fighterOverview
                                    } 
                                    |> Seq.toArray
        let fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(group.[0]) + " -- " + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(group.[group.Count() - 1])
        let saveFilePath = @"G:\Fighter Data JSON Files\" + fileName + ".json"
        File.WriteAllText(saveFilePath, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(fighterStats))
```

I have tested the functions getFighterSummary and splitArrayIntoGroups using F# Interactive. They work splendidly.

When I save a record of type FighterSummary to JSON, I see something like this for each different fighter:

```
{"fighter@": "Alessio Sakara",
"record@": {
    "Case": "Some",
    "Fields": ["19-11-0 (1 NC)"]
},
"reach@": {
    "Case": "Some",
    "Fields": [182.88]
},
"stance@": {
    "Case": "Some",
    "Fields": ["Orthodox"]
},
"fighter": "Alessio Sakara",
"record": {
    "Case": "Some",
    "Fields": ["19-11-0 (1 NC)"]
},
"reach": {
    "Case": "Some",
    "Fields": [182.88]
},
"stance": {
    "Case": "Some",
    "Fields": ["Orthodox"]}
```

The information about each fighter is saved twice -- the first time with an "@" at the end of each field name, the second time without.

What I want instead is for the information about the fighter to be saved only once, without "@" at the end of each field name.

I have read the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20982294/serialization-of-f-mutable-variable-to-json-using-json-net-generates-duplicated), in response to a question posted by someone who faced a similar problem. I have tried implementing the suggestions provided there, but they didn't work.

I would appreciate it if anyone can help me with this problem. Thank you.

EDIT:

I also have trouble deserializing JSON. When I run

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FighterSummary>(File.ReadAllText(@"G:\Fighter Data JSON Files\Fighters.json"))
```

I get the following error message:

> System.Reflection.CustomAttributeFormatException:
>   'MemberSerialization' property specified was not found. --->
>   System.Reflection.CustomAttributeFormatException:
>   'MemberSerialization' property specified was not found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice, that in the post you mentioned, they used `[<CliMutable>]` but the members themselves were not `mutable`. While looking at your code, I don't see, why you would need `mutable` (in F#). The `mutable` keyword allows assignment using `<-` which is rarely used in F#. The `[<CliMutable>]` is there, so that the *compiled code* is mutable, but it remains immutable in F# code.

This is sometimes useful when you want to use the record e.g. using reflection. And JSON.Net should be able to handle things, if you just `[<CliMutable>]` but not make the `mutable` keyword in F#.

Comment: Thanks, Daniel. I have updated my question to include a problem pertaining to deserializing JSON. Will you kindly advise me on that issue as well? (The problem persists even when I remove the 'mutable' keyword from each field.)

Comment: I was messing with it a little and simply can't reproduce your problem with or without `[<CLIMutable>]` and with or without the other attribute it just works. I used this code: https://gist.github.com/DanielFabian/93bbec50678f5e26f4b0 Also, I was running it it Newtonsoft.Json 7.0.1-beta maybe you have somehow a broken version??

Comment: Thanks for your help, Daniel. It turns out that I made a very careless mistake. Everything works fine now that I have fixed it. Thank you again!