# F# type to Json is outputting the Name@ and Name

Tags: c#, json, wpf, f#, json.net

I am using F# type and using it on the DataSource of a WPF Window
And also generating a json from it:

```
type Customer = { 
                    mutable Name: string ; 
                    mutable Phone: PhoneNumber list
                } 
               and 
                   PhoneNumber = {
                                    mutable Number: string
                                 }
```

but the output is this:

```
{"Name@":"Superhero","Phones@":[{"Number@":"111","Number":"111"},{"Number@":"222","Number":"222"},{"Number@":"333","Number":"333"}],"Name":"Superhero","Phones":[{"Number@":"111","Number":"111"},{"Number@":"222","Number":"222"},{"Number@":"333","Number":"333"}]}
```

If I change the type to:

```
type Customer = { Name: string ; Telephone: string }
```

it outputs the Json I expect:

```
{"Name":"Superhero","Phones":[{"Number":"111"},{"Number":"222"},{"Number":"333"}]}
```

But the WPF Binding throws this Exception:

> A TwoWay or OneWayToSource binding cannot work on the read-only property

This is the code that I used to generate the Json C#:

```
var phonelist = new List<PhoneNumber> { new PhoneNumber("111"),
                                        new PhoneNumber("222"),
                                        new PhoneNumber("333")
                                        };
var fsharpList = Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.ListModule.OfSeq(phonelist);  // TODO: Use a Extension Method

var c = new EntidadesFS.DO.Customer(name: "Superhero", phones: fsharpList);
var json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(c);
```

Why is this happening?
**How to only output property name, using *mutable*, without the @ at the end?**
or How to solve this?

Comment: Is the problem just that the `@` sign is getting appended to the names, or also that the properties are getting duplicated and the `@` sign is appended to one of the copy's names?

Comment: Not an `F#` dev but since this is `JSON.Net`, have you tried [JsonPropertyAttribute](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonPropertyName.htm) or look into [these](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20982294/304683)

Answer (score 3):

Based on the valuable comments to this question, and with some more searches
I was able to find a solution:

```
[<CLIMutable>]
[<JsonObject(MemberSerialization = MemberSerialization.OptIn)>]
type Customer = { 
                    [<JsonProperty>] mutable Name: string
                    [<JsonProperty>] mutable Phones: PhoneNumber list
                } 
               and [<CLIMutable>]
                   [<JsonObject(MemberSerialization = MemberSerialization.OptIn)>]
                   PhoneNumber = {
                                    [<JsonProperty>] mutable Number: string
                                 }
```

or, even better, if I keep the fields immutable (F# default), 
I just need to add the *[<CLIMutable>]* Attribute:

```
[<CLIMutable>]
type Customer = { 
                    Name: string
                    Phones: PhoneNumber list
                } 
               and 
                   [<CLIMutable>]                   
                   PhoneNumber = {
                                    Number: string
                                 }
```

Output:

```
{"Name":"Superhero","Phones":[{"Number":"111"},{"Number":"222"},{"Number":"333"}]}
```

Now this generates the **Json** as expected, and also works well with **WPF** Binding.